# apply a regex to retrieve a string

Tags: python, regex

this might be a rookie question, but how would you efficiently apply regex expressions on strings to retrieve parts of the string ? I have a concrete parsing to solve as an example.

If I have the string :

```
STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3!]
```

or

```
STRING[{val2}-!val3!-(val1)]
```

or

```
STRING[!val3!-(val1)-{val2}]
```

etc... (All 8 permutations of !val3!,(val2),{val1} that I won't bother you with).

I can do several easy finds and splits on that to achieve my purpose, but how would you do things in a clean and safe way to get something like :

`val1,val2,val3 = ...` ?

UPDATE : in the string to parse, `val1`, `val2` and `val3` are variable inputs, and the three delimiters !! () {} are there to help me know where are the three values that each have another semantic meaning.

Comment: you should change the format of your string if possible at all. use json to encode the data in a dictionary with 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' as keys. suddenly you have two problems less: how to parse the data and how to parse the data with regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with capturing groups to find matches in any order:

```
import re
def matchany(subject):
    match = re.match(
        r"""
        (?=.*\(([^()]*)\))   # Find match between () --> group 1
        (?=.*\{([^{}]*)\})   # Find match between {} --> group 2
        (?=.*!([^!]*)!)      # Find match between !! --> group 3""", 
        subject, re.VERBOSE)
    return match.groups() if match else None
```

Then you can do

```
>>> matchany("STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3!]")
('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
>>> matchany("STRING[!val3!-(val1)-{val2}]")
('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
>>> matchany("STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3]")
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a truly complete answer, you should clarify further what are the possible input strings, and what is the format of the string to match. However this is an example illustrating at least the basic matching mechanism with [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
>>> examples = '''STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3!]
... STRING[{val2}-!val3!-(val1)]
... STRING[!val3!-(val1)-{val2}]
... '''
>>> for line in examples.split('\n'):
...     print re.findall(r'val\d', 'STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3!]')
... 
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

**EDIT:** the regex `r'val\d'` instructs to match all those bits that are formed by the letters `val` + one, and only one digit.

HTH!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision, but val1 val2 val3 are generic names for actual variable data.

Comment: @jeromeG - See eyquem answer then. It also uses `re.findall` in combination with lookahead and lookbehind (i.e.: asserting that - before and after your searched values - there are certain specific characters, in your case `[]` or `()` or `!!`).

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need regex ? Based on your input, the - is looking as a seperator so:

```
>>> s = "STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3!]"

# First step, remove the "STRING[" + "]" from the source string
>>> s = s[7:-1]
>>> print s
(val1)-{val2}-!val3!

# Then, split on the '-', and remove the first/last char (mean []!! etc..)
# Work with any other values if they don't have '-' in it
>>> [x[1:-1] for x in s.split('-')]
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

Comment: that would solve my problem if val1 val2 val3 where always sorted this way. however, my value can come in all 8 permutations, that's why I have those delimiters to identify which value I'm reading.

Comment: the answer work whatever is the order, and whatever is the first/end char of val*. the only things is the val must not contain '-' char. Then this code will work

Comment: I've updated the question. val1 val2 val3 are only generic names for variable data.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

regx = re.compile('(?<=[\[-])[!({](.+?)[!)}](?=[\]-])')

for ss  in ('STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3!]',
            'STRING[{val2}-!val3!-(val1)]',
            'STRING[!val3!-(val1)-{val2}]',
            'STRING[!val3!-!val1!-{val2}]'):
    print regx.findall(ss)
```

result

```
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
['val2', 'val3', 'val1']
['val3', 'val1', 'val2']
['val3', 'val1', 'val2']
```

But the exploited string must strictly respect the pattern: without whitespaces, no one of the  charcaters ! ( { } ) followed or preceded by [ or - in the desired values (if not so preceded or followed , the assertions in my pattern take the cases correctly), etc
If necessary, the regex pattern could be improved

### Edit

I improved the pattern in order that if a value is preceded by '!' , it ends with '!',
if preceded by '(', it ends with ')',
and if preceded by '{', it ends with '}'

```
import re

regx_1 = re.compile('(?<=[\[-])'
                    '[!({]'
                    '(.+?)'
                    '[!)}]'
                    '(?=[\]-])')

regx_2 = re.compile('(?<=[\[-])'
                    '(?:'
                        '(!)'
                        '|'
                        '(\()'
                        '|'
                        '(\{)'
                    ')'
                    '(.+?)'
                    '(?(1)!|(?(2)\)|(?(3)\})))'
                    '(?=[\]\-])'
                    )

for ss  in ('STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3!]',
            'STRING[{val2}-!val3!-(val1)]',
            'STRING[!val3!-(val1)-{val2}]',
            'STRING[!val3!-!val1!-{val2}]',
            'STRING[!va}-l3!-!val)-1!-{va!-)-l2}]',):
    print ('------------------------------\n'
           '%s\n\n%s\n\n%s\n%s\n') % (ss,
                                      regx_1.findall(ss),
                                      regx_2.findall(ss),
                                      [ x[3] for x in regx_2.findall(ss)])
```

result

```
------------------------------
STRING[(val1)-{val2}-!val3!]

['val1', 'val2', 'val3']

[('', '(', '', 'val1'), ('', '', '{', 'val2'), ('!', '', '', 'val3')]
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']

------------------------------
STRING[{val2}-!val3!-(val1)]

['val2', 'val3', 'val1']

[('', '', '{', 'val2'), ('!', '', '', 'val3'), ('', '(', '', 'val1')]
['val2', 'val3', 'val1']

------------------------------
STRING[!val3!-(val1)-{val2}]

['val3', 'val1', 'val2']

[('!', '', '', 'val3'), ('', '(', '', 'val1'), ('', '', '{', 'val2')]
['val3', 'val1', 'val2']

------------------------------
STRING[!val3!-!val1!-{val2}]

['val3', 'val1', 'val2']

[('!', '', '', 'val3'), ('!', '', '', 'val1'), ('', '', '{', 'val2')]
['val3', 'val1', 'val2']

------------------------------
STRING[!va}-l3!-!val)-1!-{va!-)-l2}]

['va', 'val', 'va']

[('!', '', '', 'va}-l3'), ('!', '', '', 'val)-1'), ('', '', '{', 'va!-)-l2')]
['va}-l3', 'val)-1', 'va!-)-l2']
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse your string into a *dictionary* with "val1", "val2", "val3" as keys and the found strings as corresponding values you could use something as the below code snippet.

```
import re

examples = '''STRING[!hello!-(world)-{zup}]
STRING[{foobar}-!stack!-(overflow)]
STRING[(this)-{might}-!work!]''';

name_dict = {
  '(': 'val1',
  '{': 'val2',
  '!': 'val3'
}

for testcase in examples.split ('\n'):
  result = {}

  for x in re.split ('[!)}]-', testcase[7:-2]):
    result[name_dict[x[0]]] = x[1:]

  print result
```

output

```
{'val3': 'hello', 'val2': 'zup', 'val1': 'world'}
{'val3': 'stack', 'val2': 'foobar', 'val1': 'overflow'}
{'val3': 'work', 'val2': 'might', 'val1': 'this'}
```

Answer (score 0):

with a regular expression.

this example does not work if your values contain any of the characters used to form the end-of-value-frame '!', '}', or ')':

```
import re
s = 'your string here'
val1, val2, val3 = re.sub(r'[!{(](?P<value>.+?)[!})](?P<delimiter>-)?', '\g<value>\g<delimiter>', s).split('-')
```

Comment: This does not even attempt to preserve the order of the variables. And it fails with an `unmatched group` error on my machine using the string `"STRING[!val3!-(val1)-{val2}]"` as input because the `<delimiter>` group is optional (and thus can't be reliably used in a backreference).

Comment: true, the order remains the same as in s. But as to the other argument: I ran it on python 2.7 and had no issues regarding optional delimiters.

Comment: I get that error on Python 3.2.2 and 2.7.2 with the string `"STRING[!val3!-(val1)-{val2}]"`...